# Catching URL's where page extension is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

If a user types in the following it will work fine.

```
www.yourdomain.com/default.aspx
```

If a user types in the following, and you have customErrors enabled in your web.config, you can redirect this to a page of your choosing.

```
www.yourdomain.com/deffffault.aspx
```

If a user types in the following, and misses the web file extension altogether, **how do you** send the user to a page (and also bring along what they did type in so you can log it or direct them based on some other logic you apply).

```
www.yourdomain.com/default
```

This could apply to any of your pages where the user leaves off the extension accidentally.

```
www.yourdomain.com/about
www.yourdomain.com/customers
```

Comment: Well, do the urls without an extension work now? As a general rule, I quite much turn on what we call friendly URL's, and they are say with vs2019 turned on by default. So, you should not really have to do anything for those URL's to work out of the box. If this was a older VS project, then friendlyURL's are not the default, but you can turn them on by adding nutget package for friendly URLs (but REALLY be sure to make back up, as sometimes it can break a few things). It not clear if you looking to make Friendly URL's work, or catch all cases in which the extension is not provided.

Comment: It's to catch all cases in which the extension is not provided. This would then allow me to log to a DB table what people were trying to type in.

Comment: The closest answer I've seen to this is, "For non-ASP.NET errors, you can create a custom handler in Internet Information Services (IIS)." So, we can't do anything in code that I've ever seen work. [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362998/webforms-404-error-not-catched-if-url-has-no-aspx-extension/14363063). [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/24395wz3(v=vs.100)).